# Two mail providers for the same domain

Tags: email, email-server, gmail, g-suite

we're a small company with about 25 mail addresses. Since our current mail provider (aruba) is not reliable enough, we wanted to migrate to a more professional mail system.
I, the supposed IT manager, just proposed to migrate to Zoho mail o something like that, but a colleague of mine, supposedly not the IT manager, came with the bright idea of using Google Workspaces.
Since this service is not cheap he proposes to migrate just the 5/6 more important mailboxes to gMail, and for the other set up a secondary mail domain on our actual provider, then generate a bunch of single address mailing lists to forward the remaining mailboxes to the secondary domain.
It doesn't sound like a smart move to me: seems like an hell to mantain and might (will) generate confusion in the recipients that will get replies from a different mail address.

What's the internet opinion about this?

Answer (score 5):

you cant have two different providers for the same exact domain, but you can have a different subdomain for some emails.

you could have the important email at google , for emails@yourdomainname.tld , pointing the MX records of yourdomainname.tld to google MX servers
and less important emails on another , cheaper provider for emails@mail.yourdomainname.tld , pointing the MX records of mail.yourdomainname.tld to the other, cheaper, provider.

this is probably your best way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Online Plan 1 licenses in Office 365 are $4.00 per user per month.

Business Starter licenses in Google Workspace are $6.00 per user per month.

Forget your convoluted proposal and move your email to one of the aforementioned "professional" email systems.

Comment: We're arriving from a 12,90€/year unlimited 1 gb mailboxes. It's a big step 500/600€ year for just the email. The 1€/month mailbox of zoho seems ok to me since the volume is not that big. The convoluted proposal is of course not mine :D

Answer (score 0):

I set up something similar for a customer once. They had a bunch of mail boxes with a cheap mail hoster and that all worked fine but they had around 5 users that needed (or wanted) more integration, calendar sharing etc. So we set up office365 mailboxes for them with their proper domain as well as the dummy .onmicrosoft.com domain. In the main email provider their mailboxes were set to forward all incoming mails to userxy@domain.onmicrosoft.com. That worked pretty well and has been completely stable for several years now. Just make sure to adjust the SPF records for the additional servers that will also be sending mail for your domain...